# Using CSS to move title header to the right

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML and CSS code where I want the animation to take place

```css
.pig {
  animaton-name: apple;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframe apple {
  from {
    top: 0px;
  }
  to {
    right: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='pig'>
  <h2> About me </h2>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make my header move to the right, however it is not working, I am new to CSS, and I am using resources online but I can't figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: I would suggest you first to define all the css properties first so you know what you need to change to get your final result. Then you can put that properties and changes into the keyframes. This approach will help you in future to get css results quicker.

Answer (score 3):

first add `position : absolute` to .pig class because We need the position to be able to apply top , left , right ,bottom and then edit your `animaton-name` to `animation-name` and the last one is edit your `keyframe`  to `keyframes`

```css
  .pig {
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    position: absolute;
}

@keyframes example {
    from {
        right: 0px;
    }

    to {
        right: 200px;
    }
}
```

```html
  <div class='pig'>
    <h2> About me </h2>
  </div>
```

Comment: I voted this answer up - as a hint to others who essentially wrote the same answer - because you took the time to explain what you changed (although you didn't explain *why* the changes were necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.pig{
  animation: 3s linear 0s  apple;

}

@keyframes apple {
   from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class = 'pig'>
   <h2> About me </h2>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is it it will help you move your header towards right

```css
 .pig {
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    position: absolute;
}

@keyframes example {
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }

    to {
        left: 200px;
    }
}
```

```html
  <div class='pig'>
    <h2> About me </h2>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .pig {
    animation-name: apple;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    position: absolute;
}

@keyframes apple{
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }

    to {
        left: 200px;
    }
}
```

```html
  <div class='pig'>
    <h2> About me </h2>
  </div>
```